How to use supabase auth with nextjs and subdomains?
I have a landing page at example.com. I want to have my users sign in on that domain and be redirected to a subdomain app.example.com.
I have a login form hooked up to a server action that looks like this:
export const signInWithPassword = async (formData: FormData) => {
    const email = formData.get("email") as string;
    const password = formData.get("password") as string;
    const supabase = createClient();

    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email,
        password,
    });

    if (error) {
        return redirect("/auth/signin?auth=failed");
    }

    cookies().set("sb-session", JSON.stringify(data.session), {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        sameSite: "lax",
        path: "/",
        domain: ".example",
    });


    return redirect("https://app.example.com");
};


The cookies don't survive the redirect to the subdomain. The only docs I can find on the matter is a gh issue that references a deprecated sdk:
https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/5742
I've tried setting the cookie in the server action, and then re-authenticating and refreshing the session on the app.example.com subdomain, but the auth data is dropped.
The only thing left that I can think of would be to pass the token via query param, but that doesn't seem safe.
I'm using Nextjs app router

You might want to request the feature to edit the domain of the cookie https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/issues
